# Can't get Jest Partial Mock code examples to work

Tags: jestjs, mocking

Trying to get mocking working in Jest - especially partially mocking a dependency of the SUT.  Having trouble getting things working as I expected them to, so decided to strip it back to basics and follow the examples in the documentation exactly.  But I can't even get that to work.  The documentation I'm keen to get to work is here: [Jest Docs - mocking partials](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-partials)

I created a new project, installed jest as a devDependency and added the two tests files as suggested in the docs.  For convenience, they are:

foo-bar-baz.js

```
export const foo = 'foo';
export const bar = () => 'bar';
export default () => 'baz';
```

_*tests*_/test.js

```
//test.js
import defaultExport, {bar, foo} from '../foo-bar-baz';

jest.mock('../foo-bar-baz', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('../foo-bar-baz');

  //Mock the default export and named export 'foo'
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...originalModule,
    default: jest.fn(() => 'mocked baz'),
    foo: 'mocked foo',
  };
});

test('should do a partial mock', () => {
  const defaultExportResult = defaultExport();
  expect(defaultExportResult).toBe('mocked baz');
  expect(defaultExport).toHaveBeenCalled();

  expect(foo).toBe('mocked foo');
  expect(bar()).toBe('bar');
});
```

Then, "chasing errors" caused me to take the following steps:

- adding "scripts": {"test": "NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules npx jest"} to package.json
- adding "type": "module" to package.json
- adding "jest": {"transform": {} } to package.json
- adding `import {jest} from '@jest/globals';` to _*tests*_/test.js

At that point the test runs, but the mocking doesn't seem to have worked:

> expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality
> Expected: "mocked baz"
> Received: "baz"

I've got other Jest tests running - as long as I stick to simple expectations and no mocking or spying.
This is my first SO post, so please forgive any faux pas, and do please let me know what I need to change in my post to make it better.